# How to safely write a name of G-d in Hebrew?

Tags: words, hebrew, theology

I noticed that in English it is preferred by some to say G-d. What is the preferred way to write the/a name of G-d in *Hebrew*? For example, if you were to title a paper "G-d", how would you title it in Hebrew, safely, as it seems you are not supposed to write the [Tetragrammaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As, in Hebrew, the words which refer to "God" are actually titles calling forth qualities and characteristics, there are different ways to write things out. If you are speaking of the entirely of God, you can use the Hebrew word Hashem (lit. "The Name"), or some prefer a more mystical "Ein Sof" (the infinite).

If you are writing in Hebrew, another option is to mask one of the letters in the word by writing it as another letter which would turn El-him into Elokim (the kuf replacing the hey). That same replacement can be used in the 4 letter name so the resulting letters are yod then kuf, then vav and then kuf.

Often, people use the abbreviation of a Hey with an apostrophe (or a dalet with an apostrophe) to signal a reference to God.

Answer (score 2):

HaShem, meaning "the name" is how Jews refer to God outside of formal prayers.